# Use awk to group data by a given category and perform simple calculations

Tags: awk

I have a dataset of students that I would like to process using awk and conditional statements to group students by Continent and obtain the mean and standard deviation of the grades only for students from Asia, Europe and Africa. Below is a sample of the data and the code I have tried to implement so far.

```
id, name, country, continent_setting, grade
1, Louise Smith, UK, Europe, 7.8
2, Okio Kiomoto, Japan, Asia, 9
3, Ralph Watson, USA, America, 5.6
4, Mary Mcaann, South Africa, Africa, 7
5, Jack Thomson, Australia, Oceania, 10
6, N'dongo Mbaye, Senegal, Africa, 7.9
```

```
BEGIN {
   FS = ","
   Continent["Asia"];Continent["Europe"];Continent["Africa"]
}
FNR>1 {
   if ($4 ~ /Africa/){
       found++
       nA[$4]++
       wA[$4] += $5
       hA[$4] += $5 *$5}
   if ($4 ~ /Asia/){
       found++
       nAS[$4]++
       wAS[$4] += $5
       hAS[$4] += $5 *$5}
   else ($4 ~ /Europe/)
       found++
       nAF[$4]++
       wAF[$4] += $5
       hAF[$4] += $5 *$5}
END {print "Mean and deviation are:"
       for (i in Continent) {
       if (nA[i] > 0) {
           avgA[i] = wA[i] / nA[i]
           varA = hA[i] / nA[i] - avgA[i] * avgA[i]
           if (varA >= 0)
               stdA[i] = sqrt(var)
           else
               stdA[i] = 0
       printf avgA[i]}}}
```

The problem I have, and I would like someone to help me to solve it, is that once I collect the data of the people who belong to each of the countries, I don't know how to obtain an output similar to the following:

```
       Mean  Deviation
Africa  7.45    0.45
Europe  7.8     0
Asia    9       0
```

I have thought about saving the values in an array or something similar but I can't get it right in the code. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (_i.e._ regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)?

Answer (score 2):

here you go, with your limited data stddev will be zero for the singletons. I added the count to indicate the issue.

```
$ awk -F' *, *' -v OFS='\t' '
         NR>1 {k=$4; count[k]++; sum[k]+=$5; ssum[k]+=$5^2} 
         END {print "Continent","Count","Mean","Deviation"; 
              for(k in sum) print k, c=count[k], a=sum[k]/c, sqrt(ssum[k]/c-a^2)}' file | 
  column -ts$'\t'

Continent         Count  Mean  Deviation
Africa            2      7.45  0.45
Asia              1      9     0
Europe            1      7.8   0
Oceania           1      10    0
Northern America  1      5.6   0
```

It's almost always easier to do calculation regularly for all (unless prohibitively expensive operation) and filter out the desired subset from all results. Here...

```
$ ... | grep -E 'Continent|Asia|Europe|Africa'

Continent         Count  Mean  Deviation
Africa            2      7.45  0.45
Asia              1      9     0
Europe            1      7.8   0
```

Comment: Hi @karakfa First of all thank you very much for your contribution. However I need to do the 3 continents regular expressions and conditional statements. Is there any way to do it? Maybe something similar to my code?

Comment: If this is a homework you should have specified so. You're doing the same calculation for all continents, there is no reason to duplicate (in this case triple) the code.  If you want to do the filtering in the script just do a similar regex I used in `grep` instead one of your `if` statements.

Comment: They are not exactly homework but a university code and they are scored by the requirements they ask for and in this case 3 regular expressions associated to 3 conditional statements are required. Do you think there is a way to generate something similar without duplicating so much code in the end part of awk?

Comment: OK, if they want redundancy keep the code exactly as is. Just take hints how to print in the desired form. Also change the variables nAS,... nAF, to the first one nA,... since that's what you use in the `END` block.

Comment: When I run your code I get a syntax error pointing to the first comma after -F. Did you run the code before?

Comment: Make sure you copy it verbatim with the quotes as is. You might be new here but I'm not.

Comment: I have done exactly like you and tried to run the script as follows: gawk -f file.awk dataset.csv

Comment: @oshiono the script in the answer isn't an awk script, it's a shell script, only part of which calls awk to interpret an awk script, so if you're saving that whole script in a file and calling awk to interpret it then, yes, you'll get syntax errors as it's not awk, it's shell. Save it in a file named `foo`, make it executable with `chmod oug+x ./foo`, then run it as `./foo`. Obviously change `file` in the script to `dataset.csv` if that's your input file name.